# Pattern match on chars

Tags: frp, elm

Im pretty new to Elm (elm-server 0.9.2), and i have encountered a problem that has become quite an obstacle for me.

Here is my problem:

according to [version-0.9](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/version-0.9.elm) documentation I should be able to write:

```
stripCommas str =
  case str of
    ',' :: rest -> stripCommas rest
    c   :: rest ->  c  :: stripCommas rest
```

So to test this I basically did my own function (quite similar :) ):

```
stripNewLine str = 
  case str of
   '\n' :: rest -> stripNewLine rest
    c   :: rest ->  c  :: stripNewLine rest
```

But booth of them fails, after some debugging i notice this in the javascript:

```
var stripNewLine = function(str){
    return function(){
      switch (str.ctor) {
        case '::':
          switch (str._0) {
            case Chr '\n':
              return stripNewLine(str._1);
          }
          return _L.Cons(str._0,stripNewLine(str._1));
      }_E.Case($moduleName,'between lines 22 and 33')}();};
```

I don't know much about javascript but it seems that Chr '\n' should be Chr('\n'), tough I might be wrong...Can someone point me in the right direction here cause Im lost...

Answer (score 3):

It is an Elm bug – which has been fixed since the latest stable release – and you're right, it's about wrongly generated Javascript.

Additionally, there's also a logic problem in that example code you're copying from that announcement blog post, which is that it's doing a non-exhaustive pattern match.

Strings are lists of chars (i.e. `String` is just a `[Char]`), so a proper pattern match should handle the empty list case, i.e:

```
stripCommas str =
  case str of
    []          -> str
    ',' :: rest -> stripCommas rest
    c   :: rest ->  c  :: stripCommas rest

main = asText <| stripCommas "1,2,3,4,5"
```

You can test this [here](http://share-elm.com/sprout/5253dc04e4b0d6a98b152fd6) (select "master/HEAD" from the version options, which is a later version than the current release which has the JS generation bug).